# How to show PSDs online without letting others download it?

Tags: photoshop, psd

I have around 20 PSDs which I need to show to a few programmers. Is it possible to upload them somewhere where they can view them but not download?

Or only option is to convert all of them to JPGs one by one?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use google docs to view .psd online. Upload it to docs.google.com, select the file to view, then before sharing click "File" and toggle "Prevent viewers from downloading"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use Photoshop actions to batch convert many psd's to jpgs and upload the jpg's. If you fear that they can misuse jpg's too, add a watermark over your jpg images.

Pipeline to do this could be:

1. Window -> Actions
2. Open your PSD file
3. click, in Actions window, on the button in lower right corner "create new action"
4. Name your action
5. Click Record
6. Your actions are now being recorded.
7. Layer->Flatten image (take care now - not to accidentaly save your PSD as flattened!)
8. If it is an cmyk, convert it to rgb,if it has bleed, crop off the bleed part
9. Resize your image if needed image -> image resize
10. File -> save as...JPG
11. Close image
12. Stop recording action.

Now you can run that action on whole folder where your PSD-s resides:

1. File -> automate -> Batch
2. Choose your action, and chose your folder.
3. Choose your source folder... twaeak a little... and magic will start to happen!